# Actionscript 2 dynamic variables

Tags: variables, dynamic, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have this current snippet of code:

```
players.createEmptyMovieClip(packet[1], 10);
players.packet[1].loadMovie("duck.swf");
```

HOWEVER, on the second line, where it says "packet[1]" I want to use the VALUE of packet[1] and NOT itself. How can I accomplish this? I've tried:

```
players.createEmptyMovieClip(packet[1], 10);
players.this[packet[1]].loadMovie("duck.swf");
```

...but then I get:

> Scene=Scene 1, layer=action, frame=2, Line 86 Expected a field name
>   after '.' operator.

**EDIT:**

I finally found the solution:

```
players[packet[1]].loadMovie("duck.swf");
```

I don't need to use "this."

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

```
players[packet[1]].loadMovie("duck.swf");
```

I don't need to use "this."